# Python - Use a print/debug statement within a Lambda

Tags: python, filter, lambda

I have a `filter` in Python3 that I am applying with a lambda function. Here is my function:

```
affy_reader = csv.DictReader(filter(lambda row:
                                    not row[0].startswith('#') and
                                    str(row[0]).isdigit(),
                                    file_pointer), 
                             delimiter='\t',
                             fieldnames=affy_column_headers)
```

Is there a way that I can print the value of `row` from within this lambda function? I think I need to do it like this because `row` is only scoped within the lambda. For example, were this a LISP Lambda procedure, I believe I could do something like this:

```
affy_reader = csv.DictReader(filter(lambda row: print(row) 
                                    not row[0].startswith('#') and
                                    str(row[0]).isdigit(),
                                    file_pointer), 
                             delimiter='\t',
                             fieldnames=affy_column_headers)
```

Because the `print()` is read and executed in-line. Is there some way in Python to do this? Or if not, what is a good way for me to see this value? Thanks!

*I realize my "LISP" example is Python not LISP. I was just  trying to illustrate further what it is I am trying to do.

Comment: Do you want to print all rows, or just those that pass the filter?

Comment: I would like to print all rows I guess Tim. I am really just wanting to have a look at that row to make sure my lambda function is filtering out exactly what it needs to. I am leaning towards breaking it out into another function, as suggested...

Comment: But then you should also add something to the output that tells you which line will be filtered and which one won't - right?

Comment: To the output of the new function I create to replace this anonymous one you mean?

Comment: Check out my new edit. I hope that makes it clear what I mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with a `lambda`. Just define a helper function. That way you can also display whether a certain row is or isn't going to be filtered:

```
def filter_plus_print(row):
    result = not row[0].startswith('#') and str(row[0]).isdigit()
    print("Keeping:" if result else "Removing:", row)
    return result
```

and then do

```
affy_reader = csv.DictReader(filter(filter_plus_print, file_pointer), 
                             delimiter='\t',
                             fieldnames=affy_column_headers)
```

Comment: If you are still around, I can run the code we talked about earlier, but the print statements inside of the `filter_plus_print` function do not seem to execute. i.e. I do not see the output in my console. Any idea as to why?

Comment: @Houdini: Hm. And apart from that, the program is working correctly? By the way, I just noticed that if `str(row[0].isdigit())` is `True`, then `row[0].startswith("#")` must necessarily be false, so you can safely remove that condition.

Answer (score 5):

General Python 3.x trick to print debug info in a lambda without changing its semantics:

Original:

```
lambda: 4
```

Instrumented:

```
lambda: (print (3), 4) [1]
```

Explanation:

Both arguments of the tuple will be evaluated.

The left one, `print (3)` in the example, is relying purely on a sideeffect, i.e. in this case it will print something. You can call any function here, since any Python function will return a value. This value will be the Python predefined value `None` if a return statement is missing. This doesn't matter since the return value isn't used anywhere.

The second argument, `4` in the example, can be any expression including a function call or a call to a functor (object with overloaded round brackets). This argument is returned by the lambda function by selecting `[1]`, i.e. the second element of the tuple (indexing in Python starts at 0].

The reason why this works specifically in Python 3.x is that `print` is a "perfectly ordinary" function there, whereas in Python 2.x it was a statement.

Comment: You should write in more detail. This could have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the values within `file_pointer` by printing it directly.

```
print(file_pointer)
affy_reader = csv.DictReader(filter(lambda row:
                                    not row[0].startswith('#') and
                                    str(row[0]).isdigit(),
                                    file_pointer), 
                             delimiter='\t',
                             fieldnames=affy_column_headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no pythonic way to execute multiple statements in an anonymous function. I would suggest breaking the lambda out to a named function, like so:

```
def relevant(row):
    print(row)
    return not row[0].startswith('#') and str(row[0]).isdigit()

affy_reader = csv.DictReader(filter(relevant, file_pointer), 
                             delimiter='\t',
                             fieldnames=affy_column_headers)
```

Comment: I did use this solution, the other guy just answered first and was a bit more descriptive. I upvoted ya though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that `print(row)` returns `None` and you have to do something with it. Rather unpleasant in most cases.